Add fan control to furnace
I have a wood stove that puts out good heat but is way on one side of the house. I'd like to use my Nest thermostat to cycle the furnace blower, but the furnace control unit doesn't seem to support a fan control wire. Do I need a different control unit? I'd rather solve this gracefully with the controller and thermostat rather than splicing into the system somewhere, but that's not out of the question.




Current thermostat wiring?

I had to add a second board to my furnace when adding a second heat source to the air ducts to control the second thermostat for the fan.  Your local regulations might be important, because the person helping me, told me to ask store for the control board for a different device from a furnace.  As a non licensed furnace installer, I could not buy the board for a fuel burning furnace.

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact visible on the right side of the controller, just the two wires to ask for heat. I don't remember what they're labelled as on the Nest, but I just followed the instructions when i set it up

@crip659 "second heat source" Do you mean to allow the blower to sense and kick on based on a different heat source? That's fancier than I was expecting; I was looking for timed cycling of the blower. Nest supports that if I provide it a blower control wire

I needed the second board so a second thermostat could control the furnace blower fan, instead of the furnace having to come on.  Basically when the house/room temperature dropped the fan kick in.  The second source was an outdoor wood furnace with separate controls.

Please explain your entire heating setup. You've mentioned a wood stove, but you've posted a picture of an oil furnace.
